# how to config httpclient to use a remote dns resolve?

Tags: ssh, httpclient, reverse-proxy

I'm write a java program, which use httpclient to get some webpages.

the httpclient use a ssh socketv5 proxy.

now I can get html with ip, but can't get html with dns.

It seems had to use remote dns, How?

---

update:

1. device1(192.168.10.127) use wifi connect to network
2. server1(192.168.10.100) and device1 in a lan which can't connect to network
3. server1 use **SSH -D 127.0.0.1:1234 root@192.168.127 -N -v**
4. java program in server1 try to download homepage of google and got error with dns problem.
5. java progam try to download google(use ip), success.
6. so it must be remote proxy dns problem.

now I run dnsmasq in device1 and set server1's dns server to device1, then it works.

the question now is, can httpclient set dns, so we don't need to use dnsmasq.

Comment: It's hard to help you if we don't know what you tried. Do you have a code sample? Can you give more details about your proxy setup?

Comment: updated,sorry for poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had used anthor way to do this, http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html